# VMWare memory configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi

My VMWare host is an HP DL360 G4p running ESXi 4 Build 219382.  I've created a new VM running Windows server 2003 R2 32bit and configured it for 4GB of memory.  After installing the OS, it's only showing that it has 3GB of memory.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The windows OS is 32 bit. You need to either enable PAE or use a x64 version of windows